# 12.10: unable to upgrade/install softwares

Tags: upgrade, update-manager, update-alternatives

i have changed new release with old release in order to update also unchecked ppa. please help me out.im getting a getting a error message: W: Failed to fetch http://in.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to in.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http:  and so on......

Comment: Your /etc/apt/sources.list is incorrect:  the characters 'in.' need to be removed - the link should look like  http://old-releases.ubuntu.co... rather than  http://in.old-releases.ubuntu.co...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Charles has said, you need to remove the "in." at the start of your source URL. Open a Terminal and enter this command:  `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`

Then find the url thrown by APT in the error message and remove the "`in.`" so that the url changes from  `http://in.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages` to `http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages`

Once the change has been made, press Ctrl + O to save the changes, answer 'y' when prompted, and press Ctrl + X to exit nano.

Once that's saved, run `sudo apt-get update` and try to install your software after that's finished.

Comment: its working thank you charles an ThepromisedLAN....